# Etymology of "history" and why the "hi-" prefix?

Tags: etymology, nouns

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=history), *history* comes from the same root as *story*. If they are from the same word, where does *hi-* come from? Is it just because of the English habit of taking names from other languages verbatim or is there something more to it?

Comment: This question is a tad backwards, because looking at the etymology, it's rather clear that it's not a prefix that was added to form "history", but rather a part of the word was *lost* to form "story". *Why* that happened, however, is not obvious, so it's still a fair question to ask.

Comment: Wait until we hear herstory.

Comment: @Kristory  We deprecate constraining people to his/herstory on ELU. The consensus here is that theirstory is the natural expression.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look more closely you will see that the *hi-* was there originally, in Greek *historia* from which it was borrowed into Latin. The initial syllable was weakened and sometimes dropped in Late Latin, and reduced to *e-* in Old French, from which the word was borrowed into Middle English.

In [ME](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=78732210&egdisplay=compact&egs=78736926) it shows up as *historie, istorie, estorie* and *histoire*, all representing OF forms, probably influenced by Latin – for of course Latin was still a living written language of learning and scholarship. Alongside these a [“native” version](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=196378727&egdisplay=compact&egs=196397527), with the initial syllable entirely dropped, began to show up; this appears as *storie, stor, storri*, with plurals *stories, storise, storius,* and *storien*.

All these forms were used indifferently for any narrative account, whether formal chronicle or patent romance. It was not until Early Modern English – the 16th century – that spellings and forms began to shake down– probably, again, influenced by the status of Latin as the principal language of learning – into the contrasting *history* = factual narrative and *story* = fictional narrative.

Note that to this day French *histoire* means both story and history – as does the corresponding term in German, *Geschichte*. I imagine this is true in many other European languages.

---

EDIT:
This simplified contrast is rightly challenged by Arlen Beiler and John Lawler: *story* embraces any narrative, not only fictional narratives, and the two terms have never completely separated. But by and large, *history* has come to mean the product of the academic discipline, while *story* has come to mean an engrossing narrative. *OED 1* puts it rather neatly, I think, under Story 4 e [story of a life, institution, etc. ]:

> Originally = HISTORY 4 b; but in modern use (from association with Sense 5) implying that the course of events referred to has the kind of interest which it is the aim of fiction to create.

I must also acknowledge that over the past two generations historiographers have grown skeptical of the Rankean *eigentlich gewesen* and are much more conscious of the element of mythopoesis in their work; so in a sense *history* is collapsing back into *story*.

Comment: Story = fictional narrative? According to Google, a story is an account of something (real, imagined, or false), whereas history is the events behind a story. War stories are history, but war history is not stories, it is hate, blood, and killing (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Sorry, here's a link to the Google Dictionary. Story: http://goo.gl/60Nhl, History: http://goo.gl/uO8Nz

Comment: _Story_ means a narrative. Period. A bunch of utterances, mostly linked by "and then". _History_ is a specialized version of the general _story_; they have different senses even though they come from the same root. But one can say the same for _kind_ and _gentle_, or for _skirt_ and _shirt_. Every word has a unique history.

Comment: Story doesn't become history until it is well salted in popular acceptance.

Comment: Every correspondent files *his story* -- when there's no story, ferrets out *history* from back numbers.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler  See my edit.

Comment: @Kris  Or ... History is the stories people believe.

Comment: @StoneyB Do you have any source justification for your final paragraph? Myths are important to the historian's work, since they serve to help explain public opinion and popular values. *Myth of the Blitz* by Angus Calder (1992), for example, which records and analyses verbal memories of the Luftwaffe blitz on London, is a valuable work - since it helps explain how Londoners came to understand what took place. But I cannot accept that "history is the stories people believe". The public has a distorted understanding of almost everything that ever happened, in my experience.

Comment: @WS2 But history is also the stories which *historians* believe; and those are by the same token the stories which historians *create*. That every historian creates a coherent narrative out of the facts she herself selects as significant has been throughout my lifetime a commonplace of historiographical understanding.

Comment: @StoneyB It is an art and not a science. But it is more than "stories which people believe". A classic instance of that, in the news tonight, has been the Hillsborough inquiry (if you are familiar). The overwhelming public view, that the 96 Liverpool football fans died in (1989) as a result of hooligan activity was widely held in Britain, fuelled by tabloid newspaper headlines, and what is now known to have been a massive cover-up by the Sheffield police of their own inadequate crowd control measures. A public inquiry (using the sort of methods historians employ) has exposed the whole myth.

Comment: @WS2 Fersher; it's what Tey's Inspector Grant calls 'Tonypandy'. But what any historian will tell you is that history is a construct and historians themselves are just like other people, bound by their preconceptions and received categories; and that history must in consequence be rewritten in every generation as a new narrative.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, quite so. Each generation asks different questions.  There is even one historian I heard of working on a "women's perspective" of the Norman conquest!

Answer (score 0):

In the grammar of the Greek language there are signs signifying either quantity or quality. These are two: the " Dhasia", which is pronounsed as the English letter "h" and the "psili". The word "istoria" -in Greek "ιστορία" takes Dhasia above the letter "I" and therefore is pronounced historia or history. An example: in the word Ellen (name) the letter "E" takes Dhasia and is pronounced Helen.

Comment: This doesn't explain the "i" at all, and it only explains the "h" from the perspective of the Greek spelling system, which doesn't seem to be what the questioner was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I like [*This Is Where the Word 'History' Comes Fro*m](https://time.com/4824551/history-word-origins/) by Katy Steinmetz dated June 23 2017, because she interviewed [Dr. Philip Durkin](https://www.english.ox.ac.uk/people/dr-philip-durkin#tab-416016), Deputy Chief Editor, OED.

> American inventor Henry Ford famously said that [history](https://time.com/4826839/thucydides-trump-wonder-woman/) is “more or less bunk.” Others have characterized [history](https://time.com/history) differently: as the essence of innumerable biographies, as a picture of human crimes and misfortunes, as nothing but an agreed upon fable, as something that is bound to repeat itself.
>
> It’s hard to define such a monumental thing without grappling with the tensions between what is fact and what is fiction, as well as what was included and what was left out. So it’s only fitting that those tensions are wrapped up in the history of the word itself.
>
> The short version is that the term *history* has evolved from an ancient Greek verb that means “to know,” says the Oxford English Dictionary’s Philip Durkin. The Greek word *historia* originally meant inquiry, the act of seeking knowledge, as well as the knowledge that results from inquiry. And from there it’s a short jump to the accounts of events that a person might put together from making inquiries — what we might call *stories*.
>
> The words *story* and *history* share much of their lineage, and in previous eras, the overlap between them was much messier than it is today. “That working out of distinction,” says Durkin, “has taken centuries and centuries.” Today, we might think of the dividing line as the one between fact and fiction. Stories are fanciful tales woven at bedtime, the plots of melodramatic soap operas. That word can even be used to describe an outright lie. Histories, on the other hand, are records of events. That word refers to all time preceding this very moment and everything that really happened up to now.
>
> The distinction is still messier than that, of course. Plenty of stories — like the story of a person’s life or a “true story” on which a less-true film is based — are supposed to be factual. And plenty of stories defy easy categorization one way or the other. Take the notion of someone telling their side of a story. To them, that account might be as correct as any note about a [president’s birthplace](https://time.com/4205119/presidential-candidates-birthplace-ted-cruz-donald-trump/). To someone else, that account might be as incorrect as the notion that storks deliver babies. Yet the word stands up just fine to that stress because the term *story* has come to describe such varying amounts of truth and fiction.
>
> As the linguistic divide has evolved since the Middle Ages, we have come to expect more from *history* — that it be free from the flaws of viewpoint and selective memory that stories so often contain. Yet it isn’t, humans being the imperfect and hierarchical creatures that they are and history being something that is made rather than handed down from some omniscient scribe.
>
> That is why feminists, for example, rejected the word *history* and championed the notion of *herstory* during the 1970s, says Dictionary.com’s Jane Solomon, “to point out the fact that history has mostly come from a male perspective.” The “his” in *history* has nothing, linguistically, to do with the pronoun referring to a male person. And some critics pointed that out back in the 1970s, saying that the invention of *herstory* showed ignorance about where the word comes from. But sociolinguist Ben Zimmer says there’s evidence that the feminists knew as much at the time. And more importantly, the fact that it [sounds plausible](https://time.com/4480944/invisible-women-history/) that there would be a link can still tell us something.
>
> Take the fact that similar plays on the word have been made by people in other marginalized groups too: When jazz musician Sun Ra [quipped](https://books.google.com/books?id=o8wFfiCLGyIC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22history+is+only+his+story.+You+haven%E2%80%99t+heard+my+story+yet,%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=d8LqVU4TKl&sig=8Nv1GKx5FwWFVeUv6quE_7augVE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizhqKRitTUAhWI7CYKHRIRC7wQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22history%20is%20only%20his%20story.%20You%20haven%E2%80%99t%20heard%20my%20story%20yet%2C%E2%80%9D&f=false) that “history is only his story. You haven’t heard my story yet,” that statement might have nothing to do with etymology but it can suggest a lot about race and whether an African-American viewpoint is included in the tales passed down in textbooks. That’s why, even if the origins of the word “history” are clear, the question of who gets to decide which version of the past is the right one remains a contentious debate centuries after the term came to be.
>
> “The narrative element has always been there,” Zimmer says. In some ways, the apocryphal tale about how *history* came to describe accounts of the past “plays on what has been hiding in that word all along.”

See also [Story, storey, and history](https://redd.it/j7la7z).